# Unable to connect to Snowflake to Python

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

H,

I' unable to connect to SNowflake using Python. Via browser I'm able to connect using the same URL and Password.
Python Version -- 3.11
Snowflake - 3.0.2

I installed snowcd to investigate further and got below error. But not able to decode it.

## **Check for 4 hosts failed, display as follow:

Host: api-35a58de5.duosecurity.com
Port: 443
Type: DUO_SECURITY
Failed Check: HTTP checker
Error: http check timeout
Suggestion: Check the connection to your http host or transparent Proxy

==============================================
Host: o.ss2.us
Port: 80
Type: OCSP_RESPONDER
Failed Check: HTTP checker
Error: http check timeout
Suggestion: Check the connection to your http host or transparent Proxy

==============================================
Host: app.snowflake.com
Port: 443
Type: SNOWSIGHT_DEPLOYMENT
Failed Check: HTTP checker
Error: http check timeout
Suggestion: Check the connection to your http host or transparent Proxy

==============================================
Host: apps-api.c1.us-west-2.aws.app.snowflake.com
Port: 443
Type: SNOWSIGHT_DEPLOYMENT
Failed Check: Certificate Check
Error: certificate checker timeout
Suggestion: Check your connection to apps-api.c1.us-west-2.aws.app.snowflake.com
**

Comment: Hi.. I connected to office VPN and again used snowcd to investigate, I got "All checks Passed." Still not able to figure out why I'm unable to connect to snowflake via python..conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
                user='username',
                password='password',
                account='Accountname'
                                )

Comment: If it works when connected to the VPN but doesn’t when not connected to the VPN, then presumably your Snowflake account has network security enabled to only allow connections from the VPN

Comment: I had copied my account details ( All Capital letters) from snowflake and used the same in python. I changed it to all lowercase characters to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had copied my account details ( All Capital letters) from snowflake and used the same in python. I changed it to all lowercase characters in python  to solve the issue.